# Why is the Cancel button is not showing up in the asp:Wizard control?

Tags: asp.net

Here is a code snippet for an asp:Wizard control I have on an aspx page, but the Cancel button is not showing up.  Only next and previous buttons are showing.  Does anyone know how to resolve this?

```
<asp:Wizard 
    runat="server" 
    OnFinishButtonClick="wizCreateUser_Finish" 
    OnNextButtonClick="wizCreateUser_StepChange"
    HeaderText="SpecEx Application Form" 
    Font-Names="Arial" 
    BackColor="#336699" 
    ForeColor="White" 
    ID="wizCreateUser" 
    Font-Bold="False" 
    Style="border: outset 1px black;"
    Height="320px" 
    Width="861px" 
    ActiveStepIndex="0" 
    DisplaySideBar="False" 
    StartNextButtonImageUrl="~/images/next-btn.PNG" 
    StepNextButtonImageUrl="~/images/next-btn.PNG" 
    StepNextButtonType="Image" 
    StartNextButtonText="" 
    StartNextButtonType="Image" 
    StepNextButtonText="" 
    FinishCompleteButtonImageUrl="~/images/finish-btn.png" 
    FinishCompleteButtonType="Image" 
    FinishPreviousButtonImageUrl="~/images/previous-btn.png" 
    FinishPreviousButtonText="" 
    FinishPreviousButtonType="Image" 
    StepPreviousButtonImageUrl="~/images/previous-btn.png" 
    StepPreviousButtonText="" StepPreviousButtonType="Image"
    CancelButtonImageUrl="~/images/cancel-btn.png"  
    CancelButtonText="" 
    CancelButtonType="Image">
</asp:Wizard>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the "DisplayCancelButton" property set to "True".

Comment: Thank you, that was it.  Is there a way to have the cancel button on the left of the next and previous button?

Comment: You may want to refer to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard_members.aspx

There are a bunch of templating options there to allow you to change the layout of the Wizard control.  A quick google will get you some examples of how to template navigation controls.